# SQL self-join optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query that requires a self-join of a large table (> 1 million rows)

I'm only interested in the rows that were created today which I can filter using a recording_time column that contains the epoch time.

However, I'm not certain that the below query is actually limiting the tables BEFORE doing the join.

```
SELECT B.ani
  FROM [app].[dbo].[recordings] B
  INNER JOIN [app].[dbo].[recordings] A
  ON B.callid = A.callid AND B.dnis = A.ani
  where A.filename LIKE '%680627.wav'
  AND B.recording_time > 1485340000
```

Comment: I don't understand your question here. Can you try to explain what you are asking?

Comment: Sure, basically I want to avoid doing a self-join of the full table.  I know that the rows I'm interested are created today.   Trying to minimize the impact on the database.

Comment: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/

Comment: Add sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter rows that were created today and use that new table to join.

```
SELECT B.ani 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM [app].[dbo].[recordings] where recording_time > 1485340000 ) B
INNER JOIN ( SELECT * FROM [app].[dbo].[recordings] where recording_time > 1485340000 ) A
ON B.callid = A.callid AND B.dnis = A.ani
where A.filename LIKE '%680627.wav'
```